# How I can get the output on my browser?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache2, php-7

I am trying to run a shell command using the PHP script. Here is the script:

```
<? php
$out = shell_exec('wikitrivia "tony" ');
echo $out;
?>
```

When I am running this using commandline then I am getting the output but not on the browser. I am using the AWS EC2.
Running the PHP using the `apache2`.

I have already created the virtual environment using the instruction from  link: https://github.com/atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator#installing-with-python-34

I would like to know how I can make my code run on browser? I am getting the output on the console, but not on browser. Kindly, help me with your suggestions.

Comment: see how work functions `ob_start()` `ob_flush ()` `ob_end ()`

Answer (score 0):

If you do it with `pyvenv`, you  sourced `venv/bin/activate`, which sets up environment variables for your user. The php script inherits your environment when you run it from shell, but not when you run it from the web.

When you make an http request, the script is being executed in apache user environment. Usually apache runs as `httpd`, `www-data` or `apache` user, depending on your configuration.

You can install it [with docker](https://github.com/atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator#installing-with-docker), and change your script to

```
$out = shell_exec('docker run atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator "tony" ');
echo $out;
```

Alternatively, you can reverse-engineer what environment is required and set it up from php script.

Comment: I still see nothing on my screen, even after using your answer

Comment: Please ensure docker is up and running, e.g. with `ps aux | grep docker`, or just running the command from the shell. Ensure your apache user belongs to docker group. If not, add it like `usermod -aG docker www-data`, if your apache user is `www-data`. For debugging purposes you may like to catch stderr output: `$out = shell_exec('docker run atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator "tony" 2>&1 ');`. I think it should cover most obvious problems. If it doesn't help, please check apache error log, or enable error reporting with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on the top of your php script.